# How to obtain the Frobenius series solution to ODE when one term is multiplied by $x$ to fractional power?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

This is an ode from an old book, which I am stuck solving, since there is a term in front of $y''$ which does not have a power series. Here is the problem
$$
    x^{\frac{3}{2}} y'' + y = 0 
$$
Expansion is at $x=0$. The book shows the solution using standard form, but I do not know how they obtained it. Here is a screen shot of the book with the solution it gives

[image]

I set $a=1$ for simplicity.     Here is my attempt

Solve
$$
x^{\frac{3}{2}}y^{\prime\prime}+y=0
$$
Since $x=0$ is regular singular point, then Frobenius power series must be
used. Let the solution be represented as Frobenius power series of the form
$$
y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+r}
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime} &  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(  n+r\right)  a_{n}x^{n+r-1}\\
y^{\prime\prime} &  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(  n+r\right)  \left(
n+r-1\right)  a_{n}x^{n+r-2}
\end{align*}
Substituting the above back into the ode gives
\begin{align}
x^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(  n+r\right)  \left(
n+r-1\right)  a_{n}x^{n+r-2}\right)  +\left(  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}
x^{n+r}\right)   &  =0\nonumber\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(  n+r\right)  \left(  n+r-1\right)  a_{n}
x^{n+r-\frac{1}{2}}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+r} &  =0\tag{1A}
\end{align}
To make all powers on $x$ the same, the above becomes
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(  n+r\right)  \left(  n+r-1\right)  a_{n}
x^{n+r-\frac{1}{2}}+\sum_{n=\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty}a_{n-\frac{1}{2}}
x^{n+r-\frac{1}{2}}=0\tag{1B}
\end{equation}
The indicial equation is obtained for $n=0$. From the above this gives
$r(r-1)=0$. Hence the roots are $r_{1}=1$ and $r_{2}=0$. The roots differ by
integer. Therefore we can construct two linearly independent solutions
\begin{align*}
y_{1}\left(  x\right)   &  =x^{r_{1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}\\
y_{2}\left(  x\right)   &  =Cy_{1}\left(  x\right)  \ln\left(  x\right)
+x^{r_{2}}\left(  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}\right)
\end{align*}
Or
\begin{align*}
y_{1}\left(  x\right)   &  =x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}\\
y_{2}\left(  x\right)   &  =Cy_{1}\left(  x\right)  \ln\left(  x\right)
+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}
\end{align*}
Or
\begin{align*}
y_{1}\left(  x\right)   &  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+1}\\
y_{2}\left(  x\right)   &  =Cy_{1}\left(  x\right)  \ln\left(  x\right)
+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}
\end{align*}
Where $C$ above can be zero.  Let us find $y_{1}\left(  x\right)  $ first.
From Eq(1B), where now $r=r_{1}=1$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(  n+1\right)  \left(  n\right)  a_{n}x^{n+\frac{1}%
{2}}+\sum_{n=\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty}a_{n-\frac{1}{2}}x^{n+\frac{1}{2}}=0
$$
$n=0$ is skipped since used to find the roots. Let $a_{0}=1$. But how to find
$a_{1},a_{2},\cdots$ since the index $n$ are not integers?

The whole problem starts because $x^\frac{3}{2}$ does not have power series expansion. This cause the index to become fractional. So I have no idea how to handle this case.

Maple claims there is no series solution to this ode

```
ode:=x^(3/2)*diff(y(x),x$2)+y(x)=0
infolevel[dsolve]:=3;
dsolve(ode,y(x),series)
dsolve/series/ordinary: vector Y of initial conditions at x0 = 0 [y(0) (D(y))(0)]
dsolve/series/ordinary: trying Newton iteration
dsolve/series/direct: trying direct subs
dsolve/series/froben: trying method of Frobenius
dsolve/SERIES: Warning: no solutions found
```

Then how did the book obtain one? How to handle such case?

Answer (score 1):

As you have a fractional power in the equation, you have to assume that the series expansion also needs a fractional power of $x$ as the basis. So try
$$
y(x)=\sum a_nx^{r+sn}\\
y'(x)=\sum (r+sn)a_nx^{r-1+sn}
\\
y''(x)=\sum (r+sn)(r-1+sn)a_nx^{r-2+sn}
\\
x^{3/2}y''(x)+y(x)=\sum (r+sn)(r-1+sn)a_nx^{r-1/2+sn}+\sum a_nx^{r+sn}
$$
To get a solvable system, the second term of the first series has to be compatible with the first term of the second, which gives $s=\frac12$. The indicial equation for the lowest power is then $0=r(r-1)$, and for $r=1$ one gets the recursion for the coefficients
$$
a_{n+1}=-\frac{a_n}{(n+1)/2(1+(n+1)/2)}=-\frac{4a_n}{(n+1)(n+3)}.
$$
This directly gives the $A$ basis solution in the cited book.

Comment: Thanks. But you are using new form I have not seen before. Normally it is $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+r}$  but now you have $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{s\,n+r}$ so you added a new term $s$. Is this because the original ode had fractional powers on $x$? I have never seen this before. i.e. adding an $s$ times $n$ there. Do you know of examples where this notation is used?  I need to look more into your solution also.  I also do not see how you arrived at `the second term of the first series has to be compatible with the first term of the second`.  But will try to figure it out.

Comment: You could also first insert $y(x)=u(x^s)$ with the intent to find a normal Frobenius series for $u$. Then you get that $1/2$ has to be an integer multiple of $s$, so in the simplest case $s=1/2$.

Comment: sorry, I am not following your method. Lets say $s=\frac{1}{2}$. This is not the issue for me now. Assume it is given OK. But before doing anything, we need to make all powers on $x$ the same in all the sums. Only after that, we find $r$ and next find the recursive equation. I do not see anywhere how to made all powers of $x$ the same in all sums. Because this is the problem for me. When making all the powers the same, then the sum now start from $n=\frac{1}{2}$ which makes no sense.   This is what I did in Eq(1B).  Do you know reference that solves such a problem with fractional powers? Thank

Comment: I'll try to find a better formulation. It is not that the coefficient system becomes unsolvable. Choosing $s$ as some part of $1/2$, from the exponent equality $r-1/2+n_0s=r$, introduces sub-sequences of zero coefficients where the non-zero parts corresponds to the $n_0=1$, $s=1/2$ case.