# Any suggestions on how to get started on solving this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function, frobenius-method

The differential equation is

$$(1-x)y''(x)-y'(x)+kx^{-25/14}y(x)=0$$.

I tried a power series solution with fractional powers, like in [how to obtain Frobenius series solution to ODE when one term is multiplied by x to fractional power?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4293396/how-to-obtain-frobenius-series-solution-to-ode-when-one-term-is-multiplied-by-x), but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Linear ODE with rational power

$$ (1-x)\ y''(x) - \ y(x) +  k\ x^{-25/14} \ y(x)=0$$

Prefactors of second derivatives go between the two derivatives by the dual transformation via integration by parts of scalar products in the Hilbert space over $(0,1)

$$  
\begin{gather} 
\forall g,g(0,1)=0 : 
 \int_0^1  dx &\ g(x) ( - (1-x)  y''(x)  )  ==
  \int_0^1  dx    ( g'(x)   (1-x)   y'(x) - g(x)y'(x)
\end{gather}
$$

We have in Mathematica code

```
   D[(1-x)D[ f[x],x],x]  - k\  (x^-2) (x^\[Alpha]) f[x]

    -k x^(-2+\[Alpha]) f[x]-(f^\[Prime])[x]+(1-x) (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]
```

By trial and error, the following group of transformations has been found

```
    Together /@ 
     Collect[x^(\[Alpha] + 1) D[(1 - x) D[x^\[Beta] f[x], x], x]  - 
       k  x^-2 x^(\[Alpha] + 1 + \[Beta])
         f[x] /. {\[Beta] -> -\[Alpha]} // Simplify // Expand, 
       {f[x],  f'[x], f''[x]}] /. 
        {\[Alpha] -> 3/14} 

      -(((-(51/196) + k + (9 x)/196) f[x])/ x) + 
         (-(3/7) - (4 x)/7) Derivative[1][f][x] - 
          (-x + x^2) ( f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]
```

or more readable

$$-\left(x^2-x\right) f''(x)+\left(-\frac{4 x}{7}-\frac{3}{7}\right) f'(x)-\frac{f(x) \left(k+\frac{9 x}{196}-\frac{51}{196}\right)}{x}$$

Belive it or not, there always show up relativistic factors $\sqrt{1+k^2/4} = \cosh u$:

```
 DSolve[ 0 == -(((-(51/196) + Sinh[u]^2/4 + (9 x)/196) f[x])/ x) +  
         (-(3/7) - (4 x)/7) Derivative[1][f][x] - 
    (-x + x^2) (  f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x], f[x], x] // FullSimplify
```

$$ x^{\frac{\cosh (u)}{2}+\frac{5}{7}} \, _2F_1\left(\cosh ^2\left(\frac{u}{2}\right),\cosh ^2\left(\frac{u}{2}\right);\cosh (u)+1;x\right)$$

$$ _2F_1\left(-\sinh ^2\left(\frac{u}{2}\right),
  -\sinh ^2 \  \left(\frac{u}{2} \right);\ 1-\cosh (u);\ x  \right)$$

There are made eliminations of constant factors and square roots are taken. So the solutions, with the powers of x added, have to be checked to satisfy the original equation (as always, because solving is not a proof, it is a process of educated guessing).

Comment: Use mathjax, please.